# YAML format from JSON in Linux

Tags: json, bash, yaml, jq, key-value

I am looking easy ways to clean my `json` in linux.

**Sample Input:**

```
[{"name":"Student1","value":"John"},{"name":"Student2","value":"Jack"},{"name":"Student3","value":"Nick"},{"name":"Student4","value":"Karen"},{"name":"Student5","value":"Jonas"}]
```

**Expected Output:**
I want to save below expected output in `txt/yaml` file in linux.

```
Student1:John
Student2:Jack
Student3:Nick
Student4:Karen
Student5:Jonas
```

**My Attempt:**

```
jq '. | map([.name, .value] | join(": ")) | join("\n")' file.json >> all_param.yml;
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo It was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only missing the additional flag `--raw-output` for jq.
The command should look like

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | [.name, .value] | join(":")' file.json
```

The `--raw-output` argument makes jq print the output directly instead of printing it as a JSON string, i.e., escaping it in a string.

In your expected output you have no space after the colon, but you have it in your jq command.